Fatal error when using python Ripser on 3D point clouds
I am attempting to analyze 3D CAD models (STP/STL) for voids and similar enclosed empty spaces. For this task, I have been using Vedo to convert STL to 3D point clouds, and was trying to run Ripser with maxdim=2. I used a 3D pointcloud input of shape (7076, 3), of type float32. This resulted in a fatal error:
start = time()
dgms = ripser(obj_pts, maxdim=2)
print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time() - start))


Fatal Python error: Aborted


Main thread:
Current thread 0x00008e74 (most recent call first):
  File "C:\Users\<username>\Anaconda3\envs\<env>\lib\site-packages\ripser\ripser.py", line 321 in ripser
  File "C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_9716\1004169720.py", line 2 in <module>


Restarting kernel...

This does not happen in the default setting, maxdim=1; the output from there is the expected output. Of course, as I am looking for 3D voids, not 2D ones, I rather need the maxdim=2 option working. Any help understanding and resolving this error would be appreciated.
Alternately -- I'm very new to TDA, and am not wholly certain that Ripser is the best choice for 3D void detection in point clouds. If someone knows of a better alternative, I will happily listen.
EDIT: This appears to be a memory error. Using a point cloud generated from just a filleted cube, shape (4728,3), results in the same error. However, a randomly generated (100,3) point cloud results in a successful execution. Would still appreciate either a solution or an alternative.

The Rips filtration can quickly become huge, it may be necessary to give an upper-bound on the length of edges to limit its size, although you may miss part of the diagram that way.
In low ambient dimension (3 is low), the alpha-complex filtration is much smaller and should be the default choice (it has the same persistence as the Čech filtration, and the Rips is in general only used as an approximation of the Čech that is easier to compute than the Čech).
If you want to compute the homology of dimension 2 or more (whatever the ambient dimension) of a Rips filtration, it is usually a good idea to start by the edge-collapse simplification, which produces another Rips-like filtration with the same persistence but much fewer edges.
Alpha-complexes and edge collapses are both available for instance in the Gudhi library (disclaimer: I am a maintainer).
